# toketi-kafka-connect-iothub is archived. Is there an alternative

Tags: apache-kafka-connect, confluent-platform, azure-iot-hub

There is a kafka connect connector for iothub. This is available from the confluent website (https://www.confluent.io/hub/microsoft/kafka-connect-iothub). However, the iothub connector in kafka connect is archived (see https://github.com/Azure/toketi-kafka-connect-iothub) and the last commit dates from 2018-03-19.

In the meantime the plugin does not work with the current version and needs to be updated.

Is there an alternative repo available. Did microsoft stop supporting this? Is there a plan?

Answer (score 0):

The Kafka connector project for communicating with IoT devices is indeed retired.

If only one-way is desired, Event Hubs does have a [Kafka compatibility layer](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/event-hubs/event-hubs-for-kafka-ecosystem-overview) and IoT Hub message routing can be used to take advantage of that scenario.

You can reach out via [Azure Support Request](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/iot-fundamentals/iot-support-help#create-an-azure-support-request) if you are looking for other alternatives and we can share our roadmap under NDA. When you open the Azure Ticket, reference this SO thread.